# insertar datos de un array en un tabla HTML con Angular

Tags: html, angular, table

Estoy intentado insertar un array de 6 posiciones dentro de una table HTML con Angular, el inconveniente es que se tiene que imprimir en 2 columnas y pasar a una nueva fila hasta finalizar el array.
[image: Table Html]

```
var array = [{
"name": "prueba1",
"positionId": 1
},{
"name": "prueba2",
"positionId": 2
},{
"name": "prueba3",
"positionId": 3
},{
"name": "prueba4",
"positionId": 4
},{
"name": "prueba5",
"positionId": 5
},{
"name": "prueba6",
"positionId": 6
}]
```

Comment: Hola, ¿y qué has intentado hasta ahora? Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código de lo que hayas intentado para poder ayudarte. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que acomodar un poco el arreglo para facilitarlo. Esta es la solución que se me viene a la cabeza:

```
//Creas un arreglo para ordenar los datos
// y trabajar mas fácil en tu plantilla html
convertido = []


constructor( ){


   // Iteras sobre tu arreglo original. Pero la clave es 
   // hacerlo de dos en dos. 
   for (let i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
      //Creas un sub arreglo que guardara los pares. 
       let arrayPar = []
       // Sumas i cuando es par o 0
        arrayPar.push(this.array[i])
    //Sumas i cuando es impar
    arrayPar.push(this.array[i+1])
    //Guardas el nuevo sub arreglo en convertido
    this.convertido.push(arrayPar)
    // Le sumas a i 1 para que vaya de dos en dos. (0,1)(2,3)...
    i++
    }

}
```

El body de tu table llevaria dos `*ngFor` de esta manera:

```html
<tbody>

  <tr *ngFor="let con of convertido" >
    <td *ngFor="let c of con">{{c.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

El ejemplo en [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnnic8)